# ¿Como puedo crear un hexágono desde una imagen?

Tags: php, formas

Como puedo crear una imagen hexagonal con una imagen local, ya intente con el script que muestran aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778864/ pero no funciona.

Comment: He probado el script que has adjuntado y funciona. El log de errores te muestra algún mensaje? Qué extensiones de php tienes cargadas?

Comment: Tengo toda la librería gd activa, y el unico error que me da es que no muestra nada.

Comment: puedes darme una muestra de que funciona el script.

Comment: No sé que tipo de prueba quieres, pero la reproducción es sencilla, copio el script en una carpeta en mi servidor, copio una imagen en la misma ruta y la renombro a `doge.jpg` y accedo al script vía url, en mi caso `localhost/test/imageCrop.php` esto lo que hace es cargar una imagen jpg en el navegador, pero no sería complicado guardarla en el disco duro. ¿Qué más necesitarías?

Comment: jajajajajajajaja ya lo arregle, lo que pasa es que este sitio imprime mal el código osea que usa la codificación de espacios y slash, etc y lo repare con una herramienta online y listo funciona.

Comment: osea a lo que me refiero es que los espacios los codifica a codigos así &nbsp;, etc. perdon por las molestias y gracias.

Comment: Hola @AnimationsNow, podrías responder tu propia pregunta indicando qué has echo para resolverlo? Así si alguien se encuentra en un futuro con el mismo problema serà rápido! Gracias.

Comment: ok, está bien. :)

Comment: @AnimationsNow gracias! Creo que para auto aceptar tu respuesta tiene que pasar 1-2 días; cuándo puedas hacerlo aún mejor :)

Comment: solo un favor más. ¿como hago para cambiar la imagen ya generada de tamaño?

Comment: por cierto también me gustaría poder rotar la imagen, osea el hexágono

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es un error producido por fallo tipográfico y/o de formato al copiar el código de  otra pregunta/respuesta existente, y que no puede ser reproducido en otras computadoras.

Comment: @AnimationsNow Las dos preguntas que mencionas al final de los comentarios deberías publicarlas como preguntas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final lo resolví yo mismo, usando está herramienta online http://beta.phpformatter.com

El código original es este:

```
// doge.jpg is a squared pic
$raw = imagecreatefromjpeg('doge.jpg'); 

/* Simple math here

    A_____F
    /     \
  B/       \E
   \       /
   C\_____/D

*/
$w = imagesx($raw); 
$points = array(
     .25 * $w, .067  * $w, // A 
     0, .5   * $w, // B
     .25 * $w, .933  * $w, // C
     .75 * $w, .933  * $w, // D
     $w, .5  * $w, // E
     .75 * $w, .067  * $w  // F
);

// Create the mask
$mask = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
imagefilledpolygon($mask, $points, 6, imagecolorallocate($mask, 255, 0, 0));

// Create the new image with a transparent bg
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $w);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagealphablending($image, false);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);

// Iterate over the mask's pixels, only copy them when its red.
// Note that you could have semi-transparent colors by simply using the    mask's 
// red channel as the original color's alpha.
for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++) {
    for ($y=0; $y < $w; $y++) { 
        $m = imagecolorsforindex($mask, imagecolorat($mask, $x, $y));
        if($m['red']) {
            $color = imagecolorsforindex($raw, imagecolorat($raw, $x, $y));
            imagesetpixel($image, $x, $y, imagecolorallocatealpha($image,
                              $color['red'], $color['green'], 
                              $color['blue'], $color['alpha']));
        }
    }
}

// Display the result
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
```